# How to snap GarageBand project length to end of last region?

Tags: macos, garageband

In GarageBand, is there a shortcut for snapping the end-of-project (project length) marker to the edge of the last region in a project or track?

On-line help says to drag the marker in the ruler.  However, this can be very slow and tedious if the marker is way past the last region (this can happen after lots of edits).

Comment: I had this annoyance a long time before I learned the quick way. But it's been a while my memory is dim. I Think it was clicking where you want it to be whilst holding down a modifier key and perhaps it was cmd. my mac is broken so i cant chk this now. Also, export and import the melody and solo fm biab separately.